# change wordpress blog url

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I have to done a blog in Wordpress, and include it in to another site.

Now I got the blog in `http://www.example.com/blog`. I want to change this in to `http://blog.example.com/`.

Is it possible? How? I am new to Wordpress please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Domain Mapping.

Install the WordPress [MU Domain Mapping plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) and follow there on-page guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a **sub domain** called `blog.example.com` and install a fresh copy of Wordpress there.

Comment: That's how I do it as well on my host, which is HostGator.  But I think you can do it via Domain Mapping as well.

Comment: It is very adviseable to have the wordpress installation separate from the rest of the site. In case something get's wrong, other parts are not going down as well, e.g. when a hacker get's access to your server.